# need help for mongodb query for between optional parameter

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to create mongodb optional query in spring data but getting error. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Please note this query is for between date range

Below is the query

```
@Query(value = "{   $and: [ 
                    {$or : [ { $where: '?0 == null' } , { createdDate : {$gt : ?0} }]},
                    {$or : [ { $where: '?1 == null' } , { createdDate : {$lt : ?1} }]}
]    }")
```

Below is the generated query

```
{ "$and" : [ 
{ "$or" : [ { "$where" : "{ \"$date\" : \"2016-02-28T18:30:00.000Z\"} == null"} ,
 { "createdDate" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : "2016-02-28T18:30:00.000Z"}}}]} ,

 { "$or" : [ { "$where" : "{ \"$date\" : \"2016-03-11T18:30:00.000Z\"} == null"} ,
 { "createdDate" : { "$lt" : { "$date" : "2016-03-11T18:30:00.000Z"}}}]}
 ]}
```

getting below error

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "waitedMS" : 0 , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "Failed to call method" , "code" : 1}; nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "waitedMS" : 0 , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "Failed to call method" , "code" : 1}
```

Comment: Sorry but you are really loosing me here, and mostly since your attempt at correct syntax is so incorrect it's hard to determine what you acutally mean. [`$where`] is an argument that accepts a JavaScript function to resolve to `true/false` in criteria for document selection. This is not what you are doing. Perhaps a closer look at documentation before you ask again

Comment: Also not a fan of this `@Query` usage in spring-mongo. I think it is just pandering to those people who use similar signature attributes in hibernate, but don't have a clue what they mean. The 9/10 case with an "object" argument is you are better of just inspecting normally than trying to rationalise to named params in a method call on an object.

Comment: apologize if the above query is confusing.  I am trying to write a query to get the records between the date range. if only startdate present then i need the records which all are created after the startdate and if only todate presents then i need only the records which all are created before the todate. if both are missing then i need all the records. this is what i am trying to do.

Comment: I have done it in different way. I need to spend some time on the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not very clear, but from what I understand (based on ?0 and ?1 interpolation and your comments):

```
@Query(value = "{   $or: [ 
                    {$and : [ { toDate: { $exists: false } } , { startDate: { $exists: true } }, { createdDate : {$gt : ?0} }]},
                    {$and : [ { toDate: { $exists: true } }, { startDate: { $exists: false } } , { createdDate : {$lt : ?1} }]},
                    {$and : [ { toDate: { $exists: false } }, { startDate: { $exists: false } }
]    }")
```